# SSL and 401.3 on IIS 7.5

Tags: ssl, authentication, iis-7.5, https

I have an asp.net 4 site running on IIS 7.5.

If I browse to the home page using http it works fine. However, when I browse to the same page using https I get a 401.3 error. Using fiddler 2 I can see that the 401.3 error is being returned when the server tries to access this such as the CSS file and images which are held in sub directories of the website root.

I have the wesbite configure to run under a new app pool, which is configured to run under a Windows account. I've checked this account has access to the website root and all sub directories

I don't have much experience of SSL. Can anyone please explain what'd going wrong here.

Many thanks,

Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this wasn't related to ssl. I need to edit the "Anonymous user identity" to the Application pool identity rather than the default specific user of IUSR